# How Vite is configured with Laravel and Vue. Blank Page

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to configure a project using Laravel 9 + Vita + Vue.
I'm stuck in the same place with the blank page.
I checked in the console and vue code is not loading.
Trying differents, ways, set alias, update the apps.js, nothing works

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite bumpild && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.3.0",
        "madge": "^5.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.53.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "survey-vue": "^1.9.38",
        "vite":"^2.9.14",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.4"
    }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel(['resources/js/app.js']),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js',
            vue: 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from '/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';


createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

The worst is there not error message
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot about command npm run build.

Comment: Exactly same problem here. I think the problem is the URL of the assets in the blade directive @Vite.

Answer (score 0):

In app.blade.php change the vite path:

`@vite('resources/js/app.js')`